Converting ICS Date to YYYY:MM:DD:HH:mm
I have this bash script that fetches calendar event data from a specified ICS (iCalendar) URL and displays events for the current date. The start and end of the events is displayed in the ics format. I have not idea how I can convert the ics format to the YYYY:MM:DD:HH:mm format.
Here is my script:
# Define the ICS URL of your calendar
ics_url="your_url"

# Get today's date in YYYYMMDD format
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)

# Use curl to fetch the ICS data and process it
curl -s "$ics_url" | awk -v date="$today" '
BEGIN {
    inEvent = 0;
    matched = 0;
    eventBuffer = "";
}
/BEGIN:VEVENT/ {
    inEvent = 1;
    matched = 0;
    eventBuffer = "";  # Reset event buffer at the beginning of a new event
}
/END:VEVENT/ {
    if (matched) {
        print eventBuffer;  # Print the event buffer if matched
        print "";  # Print an empty line after each event
    }
    inEvent = 0;
}
/^DTSTART:/ {
    if (index($0, date) > 0) {
        matched = 1;
    }
    # Replace "DTSTART" with "start"
    sub(/^DTSTART:/, "start:", $0);
    eventBuffer = eventBuffer "\n" $0;
}
/^DTEND:/ {
    # Replace "DTEND" with "end"
    sub(/^DTEND:/, "end:", $0);
    eventBuffer = eventBuffer "\n" $0;
}
/^SUMMARY|DESCRIPTION/ {
    eventBuffer = eventBuffer "\n" $0;
}
' 


Example output:
start:20240502T080000Z

end:20240502T090000Z

SUMMARY:Event

Desired output:
start:2024:05:02:08:00:00

end:2024:05:02:09:00:00

SUMMARY:Event

or
start:08:00

end:09:00

SUMMARY:Event

I found a solution.
Thanks for all the answers. They helped a lot.
ics_url="your_url"

# Get today's date in YYYYMMDD format
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)

# Use curl to fetch the ICS data and process it
curl -s "$ics_url" | awk -v date="$today" '
BEGIN {
    inEvent = 0;
    matched = 0;
}
/BEGIN:VEVENT/ {
    inEvent = 1;
    matched = 0;  # Reset the matched flag at the beginning of a new event
    start = "";  # Reset variables at the start of a new event
    end = "";
    summary = "";
}
/END:VEVENT/ {
    if (matched) {
        # Extract hour and minute from start and end variables
        start1 = substr(start, 10, 2);
        start2 = substr(start, 12, 2);
        end1 = substr(end, 10, 2);
        end2 = substr(end, 12, 2);

        # Output the data in the specified order
        print "Event: " summary;
        print "start: " start1 ":" start2;
        print "end: " end1 ":" end2;
        print "";  # Print an empty line to separate events
    }
    inEvent = 0;
}
/^DTSTART:/ {
    if (index($0, date) > 0) {
        matched = 1;
    }
    # Store the start time without the label
    sub(/^DTSTART:/, "", $0);
    if (matched) {
        start = $0;
    }
}
/^DTEND:/ {
    # Store the end time without the label
    sub(/^DTEND:/, "", $0);
    if (matched) {
        end = $0;
    }
}
/^SUMMARY:/ {
    # Store the summary without the label
    sub(/^SUMMARY:/, "", $0);
    if (matched) {
        summary = $0;
    }
}'

New Output:
Event: Meeting
start: 10:30
end: 11:30

Event: Go for a walk
start: 10:00
end: 10:30


please update the question with the output from the curl -s "$ics_url" call; also update the question to show the expected result; if the curl output contains 'too many' entries then remove all but a couple entries (one that matches your requirement, one that does not match your requirement)

standard awk has substr which is longwinded but simple

^SUMMARY|DESCRIPTION may not match what you intend

please update the question with the output from the curl -s "$ics_url" call

you set and clear inEvent but never reference it; can DTSTART and DTEND occur outside of a BEGIN:VEVENT / END:VEVENT pair?

In the solution code you added, there's no point having if (matched) { in all the blocks that set variables since you test if (matched) { before using those variables.

The following update should solve your requirement:
# Define the ICS URL of your calendar
ics_url="your_url"

# Get today's date in YYYYMMDD format
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)

# Use curl to fetch the ICS data and process it
curl -s "$ics_url" | awk -v date="$today" '
BEGIN {
    inEvent = 0;
    matched = 0;
    eventBuffer = "";
}
/BEGIN:VEVENT/ {
    inEvent = 1;
    matched = 0;
    eventBuffer = "";  # Reset event buffer at the beginning of a new event
}
/END:VEVENT/ {
    if (matched) {
        print eventBuffer;  # Print the event buffer if matched
        print "";  # Print an empty line after each event
    }
    inEvent = 0;
}
/^DTSTART:/ {
    if (index($0, date) > 0) {
        matched = 1;
    }
    # Replace "DTSTART" with "start"
    t = mktime(substr($0,9,4) " " substr($0,13,2) " " substr($0,15,2) " " substr($0,18,2) " " substr($0,20,2) " " substr($0,22,2))
    line = "start:" strftime("%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S",t)
    eventBuffer = eventBuffer "\nstart:" line;
}
/^DTEND:/ {
    # Replace "DTEND" with "end"
    t = mktime(substr($0,7,4) " " substr($0,11,2) " " substr($0,13,2) " " substr($0,16,2) " " substr($0,18,2) " " substr($0,20,2))
    line = strftime("%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S",t)
    eventBuffer = eventBuffer "\nend:" line;
}
/^SUMMARY|DESCRIPTION/ {
    eventBuffer = eventBuffer "\n" $0;
}
'

Testing with the following input:
$ cat input.txt 
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Example Corp.//iCal4j 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20240502T120000Z
DTSTART:20240505T090000Z
DTEND:20240505T100000Z
SUMMARY:Team Meeting
DESCRIPTION:Weekly team meeting to discuss progress and upcoming tasks.
LOCATION:Conference Room
UID:1234567890
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20240502T120000Z
DTSTART:20240510T140000Z
DTEND:20240510T160000Z
SUMMARY:Client Presentation
DESCRIPTION:Present our latest project updates to the client.
LOCATION:Client's Office
UID:0987654321
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

The output will be:
start:start:2024:05:05:09:00:00
end:2024:05:05:10:00:00
SUMMARY:Team Meeting
DESCRIPTION:Weekly team meeting to discuss progress and upcoming tasks.


start:start:2024:05:10:14:00:00
end:2024:05:10:16:00:00
SUMMARY:Client Presentation
DESCRIPTION:Present our latest project updates to the client.

I ran it a little bit different ... I have the input as input.txt, the awk script as format.awk:
BEGIN {
    inEvent = 0;
    matched = 0;
    eventBuffer = "";
}
/BEGIN:VEVENT/ {
    inEvent = 1;
    matched = 0;
    eventBuffer = "";  # Reset event buffer at the beginning of a new event
}
/END:VEVENT/ {
    if (matched) {
        print eventBuffer;  # Print the event buffer if matched
        print "";  # Print an empty line after each event
    }
    inEvent = 0;
}
/^DTSTART:/ {
    if (index($0, date) > 0) {
        matched = 1;
    }
    # Replace "DTSTART" with "start"
    t = mktime(substr($0,9,4) " " substr($0,13,2) " " substr($0,15,2) " " substr($0,18,2) " " substr($0,20,2) " " substr($0,22,2))
    line = "start:" strftime("%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S",t)
    eventBuffer = eventBuffer "\nstart:" line;
}
/^DTEND:/ {
    # Replace "DTEND" with "end"
    t = mktime(substr($0,7,4) " " substr($0,11,2) " " substr($0,13,2) " " substr($0,16,2) " " substr($0,18,2) " " substr($0,20,2))
    line = strftime("%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S",t)
    eventBuffer = eventBuffer "\nend:" line;
}
/^SUMMARY|DESCRIPTION/ {
    eventBuffer = eventBuffer "\n" $0;
}

And using CLI:
awk -f format.awk input.txt


the output from the 1st script appears to show what happens if the (bash) variable today is not set (hence the reason you're able to show events from 2 different days - 20240505 and 20240510); invocation of the 2nd script (awk -f format.awk input.txt) is missing the -v date="${today}" clause; the mktime()/strftime() calls aren't really needed ... you could populate eventBuffer directly with the results of the various substr() calls

True. True. True. I didn't use the ${today} in my test. I used mktime to exemplify in case the formatting is required to be extended something else.

You should mention that requires GNU awk for time functions (mktime and strftime).

Did not work 1:1 for me because MacOS does not support Gawk ( I probably should have mentioned that). But i ended up using substr. Thank you for your answer!

@MoritzSchäfer MacOS does support gawk, it just doesn't come with it by default. You can easily install it and it'll save you a lot of time and effort in future if you need to use awk for additional projects.

Assumptions:

DTSTART / DTEND could occur anywhere including outside of a BEGIN:VEVENT / END:EVENT but ...
we're only interested in the DTSTART / DTEND entries that occur within a BEGIN:VEVENT / END:VEVENT pair
within a BEGIN:VEVENT / END:VEVENT pair the 4x desired data points may be in any order or even missing (if this is not true then the proposed solution may be a bit overkill but it should still generate the desired results)

OP hasn't provided the actual output from the curl call so I'm going to copy/modify azbarcea's data set:
$ cat curl.out
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Example Corp.//iCal4j 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20240502T120000Z
DTSTART:20240502T090000Z
DTEND:20240505T100000Z
SUMMARY:Team Meeting
DESCRIPTION:Weekly team meeting to discuss progress and upcoming tasks.
LOCATION:Conference Room
UID:1234567890
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT

        # scramble order of entries; remove SUMMARY

BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:Present our latest project updates to the client.
DTSTART:20240510T140000Z
DTEND:20240510T160000Z
DTSTAMP:20240502T120000Z
LOCATION:Client's Office
UID:0987654321
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR

One awk idea:
cat curl.out | awk -v date="${today}" '

function parse_dt(dt) {                                         # reformat the ICS datetime string

  if (dt ~ /[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}Z/)
     return substr(dt,1,4)  ":"  \
            substr(dt,5,2)  ":"  \
            substr(dt,7,2)  ":"  \
            substr(dt,10,2) ":"  \
            substr(dt,12,2) ":"  \
            substr(dt,14,2)
}

function print_event() {

    if (event[1] != "") {                                       # if we have a match (ie, DSTART == date) then print array
       print event[1]                                           # event[1] == DTSTART
       for (i=2;i<=4;i++)                                       # event[2] == DTEND
           if (event[i] != "")                                  # event[3] == SUMMARY
              print event[i]                                    # event[4] == DESCRIPTION
    }

    delete event                                                # clear/reset array
}

BEGIN        { FS =":"
               map["SUMMARY"]     = 3
               map["DESCRIPTION"] = 4
             }

$2=="VEVENT" { if ($1 == "BEGIN")                               # we are only interested in DSTART/DTEND pairs within a BEGIN:VEVENT/END:VEVENT pair
                  inEvent = 1

               else
               if ($1 == "END" ) {
                  print_event()
                  inEvent = 0
               }

               next
             }

inEvent      { if ($1 == "DTSTART" && index($2,date) > 0)
                  event[1] = "start:" parse_dt($2)

               else
               if ($1 == "DTEND")
                  event[2] = "end:" parse_dt($2)

               else
               if ($1 in map)                                   # SUMMARY or DESCRIPTION ?
                  event[map[$1]] = $0
             }
'

NOTE: OP would replace cat curl.out | with curl -s "$ics_curl" |
Taking for test drive ...
For today=20240502 we get:
start:2024:05:02:09:00:00
end:2024:05:05:10:00:00
SUMMARY:Team Meeting
DESCRIPTION:Weekly team meeting to discuss progress and upcoming tasks.

For today=20240510 we get:
start:2024:05:10:14:00:00
end:2024:05:10:16:00:00
DESCRIPTION:Present our latest project updates to the client.

For today=20240505 we get:
-- no ouput

If this does not address OP's requirements then it may be necessary for OP to update the question with more details (eg, actual output from the curl call, complete set of expected output).

Whenever you have tag-value pairs in your input, as in this case, I find it best to first create an array mapping tags (e.g. "DTSTART") to their associated values (v[] below) and then you can compare, print, modify whatever values you like just by indexing the array by the appropriate tag. Using any POSIX awk:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

today=$(date +%Y%m%d)

# replace this `cat` with your `curl` command
cat input.txt |
awk -v date="$today" '
    {
        if ( match($0,/^[[:upper:]]+:/) ) {
            tag = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
            v[tag] = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
        else {
            v[tag] = v[tag] ORS $0
        }
    }
    /^END:VEVENT/ {
        if ( v["DTSTART"]+0 == date ) {
            print "start:"   dfmt(v["DTSTART"])
            print "end:"     dfmt(v["DTEND"])
            print "SUMMARY:" v["SUMMARY"] ORS v["DESCRIPTION"] ORS
        }
        delete v
    }
    function dfmt(date) { return \
        substr(date,10,2) ":" \
        substr(date,12,2)
    }
'

The above would work even if your input contained multi-line DESCRIPTION or any other field (assuming it conforms to RFC 5545), e.g. given this modified version of the input provided by @azbarcea:
$ cat input.txt
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Example Corp.//iCal4j 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20240502T120000Z
DTSTART:20240503T090000Z
DTEND:20240505T100000Z
SUMMARY:Team Meeting
DESCRIPTION:Weekly team meeting to
        discuss progress and
 upcoming tasks.
LOCATION:Conference Room
UID:1234567890
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20240502T120000Z
DTSTART:20240510T140000Z
DTEND:20240510T160000Z
SUMMARY:Client
 Presentation
DESCRIPTION:
 Present our latest project
        updates to the client.
LOCATION:Client's Office
UID:0987654321
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

We would get this output:
$ ./tst.sh
start:09:00
end:10:00
SUMMARY:Team Meeting
Weekly team meeting to
        discuss progress and
 upcoming tasks.

Obviously you can tweak it to adjust the white space and/or output date format however you like and I'm combining the SUMMARY and DESCRIPTION parts in one output block since that's what the code in the question does but of course you could print them separately.
Regarding the script in the question:

You never need to do /regexp/ { sub(/regexp/, string); whatever }, you can just do sub(/regexp/, string) { whatever } to avoid duplicating /regexp/ since in both cases the sub() would only do something and whatever only be executed if /regexp/ matched. That applies to both sub()s in your script
You could just remove the whole BEGIN section since those variables will automatically be initialized to zero-or-null by awk so doing that manually adds no functionality to your script.
You should use ORS instead of hard-coding "\n"s in every eventBuffer = eventBuffer "\n" $0 so those parts will use whatever ORS setting the rest of the script uses instead of hoping/assuming the ORS will be \n.


I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
start:20240502T080000Z

end:20240502T090000Z

SUMMARY:Event

then
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}$1=="start"||$1=="end"{gsub(/[TZ]/,"");$0=gensub(/([0-9][0-9])/,":\\1","g");$0=gensub(/::([0-9][0-9]):/,":\\1",1)}{print}' file.txt

gives output
start:2024:05:02:08:00:00

end:2024:05:02:09:00:00

SUMMARY:Event

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that : is both field separator (FS) and output field separator (OFS). When encountering start or end in 1st field I remove all T and Z using gsub, then use gensub String Function to prefix every pair of digits with : and then use it again to remove : before first (superfluous) and second (inside year).

I also added an option to convert the UTC +0 time to a different time zone ( in my case +2 UTC).
     timeshift="2"

     start1 = substr(start, 10, 2);
     start2 = substr(start, 12, 2);
     start1= start1+timeshift;
 
     end1 = substr(end, 10, 2);
     end2 = substr(end, 12, 2);
     end1= end1+timeshift;

